# Push GKE node event logs to Fluentd

Tags: kubernetes, logging, google-kubernetes-engine, fluentd

I am trying **to configure Fluentd in a GKE cluster to log all Kubernetes events**, like HPA changes, pods coming up etc.

Where do GKE stores node level event logs? Looking for source path of GKE node level event logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the directory (/var/log/containers) by doing ssh into the node in which your deployment is created.

You can follow this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/customizing-stackdriver-logs-fluentd#objectives) which I used to configure cluster-level fluentd which parses all the logs to cloud logging. You can filter the event logs by using the query in cloud logging.

```
log_name = projects/[YOUR_PROJECT_ID]/logs/events
```

Comment: That guide is used to push logs to GKE logs using stack-logging-agent. Also their config for fetching node event logs is not supported anymore by fluentd.

Comment: I am using event-exporter for pushing logs to elasticsearch. Works fine.